# Path based routing for Microservices in AWS ECS with API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

We are deploying node microservices for the first time in AWS ECS and each services are listening on dynamic ports.

The following are the APIs of the microservices exposing while starting the node application.

**ANIMAL MicroService**

```
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/:id, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/getAll, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RoutesResolver] dogPlanController {/dog}: +0ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dog/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dog, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dog/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
```

**Bird MicroService**

```
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/bird/:id, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/bird/getAll, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/bird, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/bird/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/bird/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RoutesResolver] eaglePlanController {/eagle}: +0ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/eagle/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/eagle, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 8:12:30 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/eagle/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
```

**Users MicroService**

```
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/healthcheck, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RoutesResolver] SsoController {/sso}: +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/sso, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/signup, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/sendotp, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/verifyOtp, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/login, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/duplicateUserName, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/resetPasswordOtp, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/resetPassword, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RoutesResolver] UserController {/user}: +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/questionnaire/:id, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/questionnaire/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/userList, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/connectWearable, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 28   - 12/21/2020, 11:29:32 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/user/getArticles, POST} route +1ms
```

**Backend MicroService**

```
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/signup, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/login, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RoutesResolver] animalController {/animal}: +0ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/color, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/color, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 29   - 12/22/2020, 12:02:28 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/animal/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
..
..
..
..
```

Developers are expecting the following routing.

**Note:** carefully observe the routing they are requesting.

For ANIMAL MicroServices,

```
example.com/animal  -->>  animal-microservice-url/animal

example.com/animal/dog  -->>  animal-microservice-url/dog
```

For USER MicroServices,

```
example.com/user  -->> user-microservice-url/user

example.com/user/auth  -->> user-microservice-url/auth

example.com/user/sso  -->> user-microservice-url/sso
```

Can someone help me to achieve this in AWS environment.?

I tried ALB path based routing which wasn't fruitful given the scenario as ALB doesn't strip off the postfixes in alburl.

I have also tried API Gateway with ALB. I setup few ALB path based routes such that it can accept requests from apigateway & forward them to target groups.

However, I'm experiencing trouble while setting `wildcard, *, in ALB path based routing' alike in APIGateway to route all postfixes to one url.

example:

```
apigatewayurl.com/animal    -->>    alburl.com/animal

apigatewayurl.com/animal/dog    -->>    alburl.com/dog
```

The above two are working fine.

But the following are not.

```
apigatewayurl.com/animal/:id    -->>    alburl.com/animal/:id

apigatewayurl.com/animal/getAll -->>    alburl.com/animal/getAll

apigatewayurl.com/animal/dog/:id    -->>    alburl.com/dog/:id
```

How can I create an HTTP API route such that it access all the postfixes in alburl from apigatewayurl?

Like, when I enter `apigatewayurl.com/animal/dog/*    -->>    alburl.com/dog/*`

I tried present the issue as possible as I can.

Please feel free to ask about configuration.

If this can be done via any other service in AWS, please suggest me here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible. because here ALB just checks path, it just verifies whether given path is equal to the one mention there , it cant accept values.. You are sending values in URL.

My suggestion is that - send id or your data values in body of your request ,instead sending those in request URL. and catch those value in your API

Comment: yeah. We have tried API Gateway but we figured it's not gonna work. Developers are changed the backend code with global prefixes.